# Rounding using mutate and replace - dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rounding

I have the following data:

```
library(dplyr)

d <- data_frame(
region = c('all', 'nj', 'rkl', 'all'),
place = c("one", "two","three", "four"),
figures= c(5, 7, 4, 8),
figures2 = c(3, 5, 6, 7))
```

I want to use `mutate` and `replace` in dplyr to round some of the rows but not other. So this is my code:

```
d %>%
  mutate(figures = replace(figures, region == 'all' & place !='two', 
round(d$figures/10)*10)) %>% 
  mutate(figures2 = replace(figures2, region == 'all' & place !='one', 
round(d$figures/10)*10)) -> d2
```

This actually does what I want it to do. However I get the following warning message `In x[list] <- values :number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`. I would normally ignore this as the code is doing what I want it to do. However, when applying the code to a larger data set the rounding stops working as I would expect.

Does anyone know why this might be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually trying to do is better wrapped in an `if_else` than using `replace`:

```
d %>%
  mutate(figures = if_else(region == 'all' & place !='two', round(figures/10)*10, figures), 
         figures2 = if_else(region == 'all' & place !='one', round(figures/10)*10, figures2))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
#   region place figures figures2
#   <chr>  <chr>   <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 all    one         0        3
# 2 nj     two         7        5
# 3 rkl    three       4        6
# 4 all    four       10       10
```

`replace(x, list, values)` is similar to `x[list] <- values`, but without changing `x`itself. Thus it creates a vectore where the values of `x` at indices `list` are replaced by `values`. Thus it expects, that `list` and `values` are of equal length. If not, they are recycled.

In your case now lets have a closer look at the first replacement, as the second one has essentially the same issue. Although at first it seems that the two vectors (`region == 'all' & place !='two'` and `round(figures/10)*10`) are of same length, they are actually not as only the two `TRUE` values of `region == 'all' & place !='two'` count. Thus you get the warning message, because you are trying to use four values (`round(figures/10)*10`) for replacement of two values.